# How to click all the link one after other which has same class name in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

It is clicking the first element and rest not, Here I have to click all the links one after other.

HTML code:

```
<div class = "MangoList">
  <ul class = "Mangos">
   <li class = "MangoLi">
     <a href="#" class = "MoreInfo">
       <img src="-------------" class="mangoImage" alt="apple" title="----">
        </a>
    <li class = "MangoLi"></li>
<li class = "MangoLi"></li>
<li class = "MangoLi"></li>
<li class = "MangoLi"></li>
<li class = "MangoLi"></li>
      .
      .
      .  ---------> 50 li
      . 

<li class = "MangoLi"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code

```
def links
  @browser.elements(:css => "div.MangoList ul li a")
end

def links_text
  links.each do |link_elements|
    link_elements.click
    sleep(3)
end

Error:-Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fa9b907d0 id="0.011786506854683632-5">}
```

Comment: Are the links navigating to another page when clicked?

Comment: Yes, It is navigating to another page

Comment: Then your code won't work..you need to find each link one by one after navigating to another page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest [Watir 6.0 beta](http://watir.github.io/watir-6-beta5/)

We just added support for relocating elements from inside a collection.